# How to find or get files in Directory with Specific word in the file name Visual Basic.net?

Tags: vb.net

I need to get files from a directory containing specific characters in it's name:
The following code below will return any file with the `.csv` extension. The problem is there are other csv file I need to leave alone or not get.

```
Dim FileLocation As DirectoryInfo = _
 New DirectoryInfo("C:\Folder\Subfolder\Data\Input\")

Dim fi As FileInfo() = FileLocation.GetFiles("*.csv")
```

Instead of getting any csv file, I would like to get a file with the word **data**, so any file name containing the word data. Example: ***my_data_file.csv***

How do I do this with the code above?

Comment: Have you tried FileLocation.GetFiles("\*my_data_file.csv\*") or FileLocation.GetFiles("\*data\*") ? It should work.

Comment: Yes I tried that, I should have stated that the file name has date/time appended to it and so I cannot use the entire file name because the date/time appended issue. Example: my_data_file_10_16_2013_12_14PM.csv

Comment: I don't quite understand. By putting wildcard star it doesn't mather if there's a date/time appended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the filter with the string you want to account for (caps will automatically be taken care of):

```
Dim fi As FileInfo() = FileLocation.GetFiles("*data*.csv")
```

In any case, bear in mind that this filtering is not "too accurate". For example, the code above would also account for any file (including "data"), whose extension **includes** `csv` (e.g., *.csva, *.csvb, etc.). If you want a 100%-reliable approach you should better set up a loop and carry out the filtering "manually"; loops are pretty fast and you wouldn't even notice the difference.

Example of a loop:

```
Dim fi As List(Of FileInfo) = New List(Of FileInfo)
For Each File In FileLocation.GetFiles()
    If (File IsNot Nothing) Then
        If (Path.GetExtension(File.ToString.ToLower) = ".csv") Then
            If (File.ToString.ToLower.Contains("data")) Then fi.Add(File)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This code will work for sure under your exact requirements and might take care of more complex requests. I have accounted for a `List` just to show the point clearer.

Comment: Thanks my friend: Plenty of ideas/explanation to help me started.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use LINQ extensions then you can do it this way:

```
' Get Files {directory} {recursive} {ext} {word in filename}
Private Function Get_Files(ByVal directory As String, _
                           ByVal recursive As IO.SearchOption, _
                           ByVal ext As String, _
                           ByVal with_word_in_filename As String) As List(Of IO.FileInfo)

    Return IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*" & If(ext.StartsWith("*"), ext.Substring(1), ext), recursive) _
                       .Where(Function(o) o.ToLower.Contains(with_word_in_filename.ToLower)) _
                       .Select(Function(p) New IO.FileInfo(p)).ToList

End Function
```

Usage example:

```
    For Each file As IO.FileInfo In Get_Files("C:\Folder\Subfolder\Data\Input\", _
                                              IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, _
                                              "csv", _
                                              "data")
        MsgBox(file.Name)

    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have added this as a comment to the accepted answer, but I do not have enough points to do so:

I just wanted to add varocarbas's answer that, if anyone was wondering (as I was) if this would work in a web scenario as well, it will. Just place the web path inside `Server.MapPath()` like this:

```
Dim FileLocation As DirectoryInfo = 
 New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/Folder/SubFolder/Data/Input/"))
```

**NOTE:** Will NOT work with full url's (no 'http://www.123.com').

Answer (score 1):

Replace the wildcard search below "*.*" with your search criteria, for example you want all files that start with name "Hospital*"

---

```
Dim Folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\SampleFolder")

For Each File as IO.FileInfo in Folder.GetFiles("*.*",IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       ListBox1.Items.Add(File.FullName)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\SampleFolder")
For Each File as IO.FileInfo in Folder.GetFiles("*.*",IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(File.FullName)
    Application.DoEvents()
Next
```

Comment: This does not appear to get only files that have a specific word in their name.